# Node express param issue

Tags: node.js, express

we are using Node.js + Express as back-end for an Angular2 app. One of the modules of the back-end is responsible for the information gathering about products, based on barcode, which is a param for the Express router. Currently, we're facing an issue when adding a GET request route that does not use the barcode param.

The router file looks as follows:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const prodCtrl = require('./controller');
const auth = require('../middlewares/authenticationBearer');

module.exports.init = function(app) {

    router.param('barcode', prodCtrl.findById);
    router.get('/products/:barcode', auth.bearer(), prodCtrl.getProduct);
    router.post('/products/article', auth.bearer(), prodCtrl.getProductData);
    router.get('/products/csv', auth.bearer(), prodCtrl.csv);
    return router;

}
```

The problem is the `/products/csv` route. In its current position, calling the route gives a 404 error seemingly because the param `barcode` is expected, as the function `prodCtrl.findById` is called first. By moving this route before the `/products/:barcode` route like so:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const prodCtrl = require('./controller');
const auth = require('../middlewares/authenticationBearer');

module.exports.init = function(app) {

    router.param('barcode', prodCtrl.findById);
    router.get('/products/csv', auth.bearer(), prodCtrl.csv);
    router.get('/products/:barcode', auth.bearer(), prodCtrl.getProduct);
    router.post('/products/article', auth.bearer(), prodCtrl.getProductData);
    return router;

}
```

the code works fine. Is this a bug in Express? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: That's the way routes work, The more generic is executed first and sends the response, before the least generic is executed. You need to put the least generic routes before the generic ones (this includes `/products/article` as well

Comment: Thank you for the incredibly fast answer, will change the other route directly!

Comment: You still may keep the order as it is if you apply some validation on the barcode parameter so that the route may not match if the criteria is not satisfied. I use [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-route-params) to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You should put '/products/:barcode' route after '/products/article' because it blocks the request to get to the article (the barcode param catch any suffix)